# AngularJS Directive interacting with a parent function including params

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in my main controller I have a function to set messages on the page:

```
function setMessageState(showSuccess, showError, message) {
        vm.showSuccessMessage = showSuccess;
        vm.showErrorMessage = showError;
        vm.message = message;
    }
```

Within my main controller and service I relay messages to the user by calling this if the service succeeds or fails in retrieving data.

I have moved one of my repeaters into a directive which handles iteration of tabular data but part of this relies on calling the setMessageState function and feeding back the parameters into the main VM.

Can anyone assist in how I can call my setMessageState function from the directive with the included params?

I did try including setMessageState: "&" but while dupressing the issue of setMessageState is not defined it didn't call the function

My Directive is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
//Define the Controller
angular
    .module("tpAccStatus")
    .directive("tpAccStatusTransactionRow", tpAccStatusTransactionRow);

function tpAccStatusTransactionRow() {
    return {
        scope: {
            trans: "=tpAccStatusTransactionRow",
            accountNumber: "="
        },
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "tpAccStatusTransactionRow.directive.html",
        bindToController: true,
        controller: "tpAccStatusTransactionRowCtrl",
        controllerAs: "transCtrl"
    };
}

})();
```

And my Directive Controller has a function which calls (needs to call) upon that parent controller function:

```
function requestStatementErrored(error) {
        vm.busy = false;
        vm.setMessageState(false, true, "Problem obtaining details");
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The directive wont know anything about `vm` in your parent, instead, you can add a scope property to your directive that is then bound to a reference to the function in your parent

So:

```
scope: {
            trans: "=tpAccStatusTransactionRow",
            accountNumber: "=",
            messageStateFn: "="
    }
```

Then when using your directive, you can set like so:

```
<tr tpAccStatusTransactionRow messageStateFn="vm.setMessageState"></tr>
```

And in your directive controller:

```
function requestStatementErrored(error) {
        scope.setMessageState(false, true, "Problem obtaining details");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this from your directive,

```
scope: {
        trans: "=tpAccStatusTransactionRow",
        accountNumber: "=",
        setMessageState: '&'
    },

function requestStatementErrored(error) {
   vm.setMessageState({showSuccess: false, showError: true, message: "Problem obtaining details");
},
```

and in HTML,

```
<tr tpAccStatusTransactionRow set-message-state="vm.setMessageState"></tr>
```